# GUI framework Java

Tags: java, user-interface, frameworks, toolkit, docking

I am looking for some framework or toolkit (style drag and drop) for creating gui in Java. I need to do quite complex application with dockings, toolbars, tables etc.

Which one would be best?

Comment: [VLDocking](http://vldocking.com) is an easy way to add a docking UI, it won't consume your application's design like an RCP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Netbeans *Platform* might be what you are looking for, it is based on Swing, and the Netbeans IDE can be a showcase for it, check http://platform.netbeans.org/
I think the equivalent on SWT is http://www.eclipse.org/platform/

Comment: that looks good, but I hope it would be more user friendly than XUI that I recently tried.

Comment: GREAT. I've never thought the modules making is as simple

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a GUI builder, [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) has a decent one.   Otherwise, you can just write it yourself in Swing or SWT?

Comment: yes, I know swing, but there is needed a lot of code to write It would be slave's job I think.. And, is anywhere tutorial how to write bean?

Comment: edit: I think you were speaking about default installed swing designer to netBeans. NetBeans platform seems to be goot at first point of view

Comment: Swing is really good these days and comes bundled with the JRE.  The Netbeans GUI builder is excellent, too.

Answer (score 2):

Start reading  [Swing Architecture](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html) and then use [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) UI builder and finally complement it with [JIDE Software](https://www.jidesoft.com/) libraries.

[image]

JIDE have several libraries, for instance:

JIDE Docking:

[image]

JIDE Grids:

[image]

And many more. The only inconvenient I see is, you need a good understanding on how does Swing  works before using it ( or you can acquire that knowledge in the process )

Comment: Yes, I am new in doing gui, only thing I created till now were easy projects with couple of panels.

Comment: It looks like you'll have a good change going the way I just told you. Read that article and use JIDE from Netbeans UI builder. You'll learn a lot   in the process. When you have a doubt, comeback to SO and ask it.

Answer (score 1):

[eclipse rcp](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform), [spring rich client](http://www.springsource.org/spring-rcp), [griffon](http://griffon.codehaus.org/)

all of these frameworks are good to avoid writing boiler-plate code all over again (support for docking, window management, dialog management, preferences management).

i must note that complete drag 'n drop is not supported in none of them out of the box, but there are IDE's that help you in building Swing panels, components, ... in a visual editor. both Eclipse IDE and NetBeans IDE have a GUI Builder/visual editor.

my prefered choice is spring rich client because it's easy to get started, it's swing-based, it integrates with docking frameworks, component libraries, ... and it uses spring.

if you need a pluggable architecture then you should take a look at eclipse, or netbeans.

edited: i mean eclipse rcp